# No grub after switching to "boot in secure mode" (Windows8) after Ubuntu being installed

Tags: boot, grub2, secure-boot

I installed successfully Lubuntu 14.10 alongside Windows8. Being tired of seeing "Booting in insecure mode..." as the PC turned on, I enabled again "boot in secure mode" from Win. As a result the Grub didn't run anymore when I turned the PC on; so I disabled again "boot in secure mode" but Grub continues not to show up. 
1) How can I fix the problem?
2) Besides, is there a way to hide "booting in insecure mode.." when starting the PC?
Thank you!!

Comment: Booting in secure mode... is actually a bug in Utopic that can't be worked around right now. The Secure Mode in Windows is a completely different, unrelated setting that can only make things worse. Boot into Utopic and update your system, maybe a fix has been released by now...

Comment: What brand computer do you have?

Comment: HP Pavilion (i7-4500/8GB RAM)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting one of two identical Boot options in Bios. I am not a pro, only a user. But the message gone away. Maybe this helps...